# How to parse an unusual JSON file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a JSON file in my project that looks like this:

```
{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}
```

There are no commas or array items or anything just as it is. I'm not sure how I can work with this data and parse it.

I'd rather not have to modify the file in case it needs to be updated again. I downloaded it from the API website (http://openweathermap.org/).

Comment: That's not valid json... looks like you're missing the array delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

I think the format you're looking at isn't exactly valid JSON. It looks more like newline-delimited JSON (aka [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)).

Each line is a valid JSON object, so your best bet may be to parse each line separately rather than treating the entire file as one JSON object.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? I'm not sure how to go about it.